# Need help to identify a proper DBMS system for stand alone software system

Tags: software-development, java, database

I am a final year IT student and I need to do a project to finish the degree.

I have a an idea about account management system for a local store. This system simplifies manipulation of day books and ledgers. I want to develop this system using the Java programming language. can anybody suggest me a database management system to support for developing a stand alone system in Java.

Comment: You need to be more specific with your database requirements. How do you define 'stand alone'? # users, servers, OS, browser or executable, etc etc

Comment: the application should run on windows 7 PC

Comment: As it should be for Java, "run on Windows" seems pretty irrelevant. More important is, as Jan already asked: Define "stand-alone", define "proper", name the features it should support. As it currently stands, your question is much too broad.

Comment: my system is simple require DBMS for store data which is more suitable DBMS for java development?

Comment: what are the tools should I use for develop simple stock management system using java.